# Crash NSProxy doesNotRecognizeSelector:

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Fabric shows me that a lot of users has the following crash in my app

[image: crash]

If I expand I see the following stack

```
 Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
 0  CoreFoundation                 0x18ef201c0 __exceptionPreprocess
 1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18d95855c objc_exception_throw
 2  CoreFoundation                 0x18ef20108 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
 3  Foundation                     0x18f9eb714 -[NSProxy doesNotRecognizeSelector:]
 4  CoreFoundation                 0x18ef24278 ___forwarding___
 5  CoreFoundation                 0x18ee1e59c _CF_forwarding_prep_0
 6  WatchConnectivity              0x1a39caff0 __57-[WCSession onqueue_completeSwitchTask:withSessionState:]_block_invoke
 7  Foundation                     0x18f9e17e4 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
 8  Foundation                     0x18f926358 -[NSBlockOperation main]
 9  Foundation                     0x18f916954 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:]
 10 Foundation                     0x18f9e3b90 __NSOQSchedule_f
 11 libdispatch.dylib              0x18dda91c0 _dispatch_client_callout
 12 libdispatch.dylib              0x18ddb7444 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain
 13 libdispatch.dylib              0x18ddac9a8 _dispatch_queue_invoke
 14 libdispatch.dylib              0x18ddb938c _dispatch_root_queue_drain
 15 libdispatch.dylib              0x18ddb90ec _dispatch_worker_thread3
 16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18dfb12c8 _pthread_wqthread
 17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18dfb0db4 start_wqthread
```

My **suppose** is that there is something that doesn't work with WatchKit. In my app there is a class that is ready to transfer data to watch kit app but in this moment in build phases there is no reference to watch app and watch kit extension.

The code in my class is

```
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity

class WatchManager: NSObject
{
    func setLanguage(localization: String)
    {
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            if WCSession.isSupported() {
                let watchSession = WCSession.defaultSession()
                watchSession.delegate = self
                watchSession.activateSession()
                if watchSession.paired && watchSession.watchAppInstalled {
                    watchSession.transferUserInfo(["localization": localization])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension WatchManager: WCSessionDelegate
{
    @available(iOS 9.3, *)
    func session(session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWithState activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: NSError?)
    { }

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(session: WCSession)
    { }

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func sessionDidDeactivate(session: WCSession)
    { }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your app is using an `NSProxy` subclass as the `WCSession`'s delegate. Is that the case? If so try changing it to an `NSObject` subclass.

Comment: Hi ccjensen, thank you for your replay. As you can see in my code I've a class WatchManager that is a subclass of NSObject and there is a extension in which I've inserted all methods of delegate. I've no NSProxy subclass in my project.

Comment: Are you using any other frameworks that could be interacting with the WCSession object (common ones are advertising and user tracking ones)?